# What is the most straightforward way to assign html to an HTML element?

Tags: jquery, html, visual-studio, webmatrix-3

I have an html file in my project's Contents folder. I have a div with an ID of "FictionContent" that I want to assign the contents of that HTML file.

Is the following a good way to do that:

```
$('#FictionContent').html('Content/huckfinn.html');
```

?

Will the jQuery understand "Content" as a subfolder and thus know where to grab the html? If not, what is a workaround for doing something as similar as possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('#FictionContent').load('Content/huckfinn.html');
```

Answer (score 2):

Two examples over here:

**Content from a variable**

```
var mycontent = "Hello World";
$('#FictionContent').html(mycontent);
```

**Content from your html file**

```
$('#FictionContent').load('Content/huckfinn.html');
```